# checking text instead of session variable

Tags: php, html

Not sure if this is correct, but I realized something interesting, maybe something I did not learn yet.

So I have a submission form being submitted from `admin.php`
(form post to addcar.php). When `addcar.php` is done executing it returns the user to the admin.php page with a success message as follows:

```
$_SESSION['Message'] = "Success";
header("Location: admin.php?Message=".$_SESSION['Message']);
```

On the admin.php, I have the following code to check for the message on the return so that a success message can be displayed:

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['Message'])){
echo '<script>alert("Added");</script>';
unset($_SESSION['Message']);}
?>
```

However, it appears the `isset` is checking `?Message=` and not the actual `$_SESSION['Message']` variable ! This is the case because if I modify the url and include ?Message=TEST123, it still executes the success message. Why is this happening? Shouldn't isset check for the variable and not the text in the return url?

Comment: To work with `$_SESSION`, you need to add `session_start()` on top of  your script.

Comment: @JulianDavid I do indeed have that

Comment: @JulianDavid But it appears the session variable is not being checked, rather the text in the return URL is..

Comment: Do you have more code below of your `header()`? You could try using `exit` after that.

Comment: @JulianDavid I think I fixed the error, I moved the isset code to the end of the admin.php page, but I still would like some explanation as to why ?Message was being checked instead of the actual session variable

Comment: If you want to validate the session variable directly, you have to use `isset($_SESSION['Message'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) $_REQUEST['Message'] - checks for query string params 'Message' not session variable and yes it checks variable 'Message'.
2) isset only checks if query param 'message' is set or not and doesn't care for what its value is.and I guess you need something like this.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['Message']) && $_REQUEST['Message']=='success')
{
    ...........
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So I also just discovered as to why the session variable is not getting passed back. In another instance of the exact code I had an issue with, I used something similar to make sure the admin is authenticated. But I had this in my code too: session_unset(); and session_destroy(); which was destroying the session variable. So that was why I used REQUEST because I couldn't figure out why the session variable wasn't showing up. It was because I was destroying the session even before passing the variable back.